# About Ffmpeg,Console show 'frame=0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=0kB time=00:00:00.00' No data pull&push

Tags: java, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I want to use Ffmpeg to pull&push video stream from HLS to RTMP.at first it's normal,but when I open more,it's run normally ,but no video data pull&push

Environment：Windows64+Nginx-rtmp-static+Ffmpeg-static+Java1.8

**It's useless,even if I restart rtmp-server.**

```
ffmpeg -i xxx/live.m3u8 -vcodec h264-s 720*480 -an -f flv -y rtmp://xxx
```

The first few video streams is normal,but when I **open more streams** (5+),
it run normally,but no data pull.like this.

```
2019-01-08 10:58:15.658  INFO ->frame=0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=720 speed=   0x
2019-01-08 10:58:16.598  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efc568280] Opening 'xxx/1/live.m3u8' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:16.984  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efb1200c0] Opening 'xxx/1/seghik30.ts' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:17.083  INFO ->frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=744 speed=   0x    
2019-01-08 10:58:18.033  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efc568280] Opening 'xxx/1/live.m3u8' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:18.146  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efb1200c0] Opening 'xxx/1/seghik31.ts' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:18.267  INFO ->frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=770 speed=   0x    
2019-01-08 10:58:19.220  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efc568280] Opening 'xxx/1/live.m3u8' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:19.317  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efb1200c0] Opening 'xxx/1/seghik32.ts' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:19.415  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efb138600] Opening 'xxx/1/seghik33.ts' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:19.494  INFO ->frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=795 speed=   0x    
2019-01-08 10:58:20.375  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efc568280] Opening 'xxx/1/live.m3u8' for reading
2019-01-08 10:58:20.486  INFO ->[http @ 0000015efb138600] Opening 'xxx/1/seghik34.ts' for reading
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, I try rewrite command 'vcodec copy' ,it run normal,but at the same time  **the '-s' is Invalid**

Comment: OK.This problem is caused by the video  source. It's not standard HLS Stream